# Button that sends back the next message

Tags: python, button, telebot

I'm learning to create bots and got stuck with creating a button, that would send back the next message. For example: it's a quest bot, user entered some discovered code -> got a message with instructions and a button 'Continue' -> **after tapping the button gets the instruction for the next step**.

First I tried to do so using callback_data='Next step message', but figured out that it's not the field i need. I read the documentation, but still don't understand why this field is needed (if you could, please explain it in P.S.)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def mess_one(message):
    if message.text.casefold() == '11.09.1997':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Continue', #???))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Так держать! Ты нашла новую карту", reply_markup=markup)
    
    else: 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "I don't understand")
```

So what should I put instead of ??? to send user back some next message?